# How to scale horizontally in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a distributed kafka connector with 10 tasks and simply launching another process with same configuration (group.id etc) allows Kafka to distribute the tasks equally on these processes.

However, I would like to control the number of tasks to be available on each of these processes. Can I create another connector in Kafka with a different number of tasks? Although I don't see any mechanisms to associate a process with only 1 kafka connector and suspect Kafka with distribute them both equally.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Launching another process doesn't guarantee equal task balance, but if you run another connector, from the same topics, in your cluster, then that connector name would have a different consumer group, I believe

Comment: different group.id would cause same message to be sent to both groups. I just want to control the number of tasks for each node instead of equal distribution.

Comment: That's not part of the protocol. You can only control tasks per connector, not per worker